# What's the physical significance of using fourier transform for diffraction?

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, diffraction

I am studying some basic idea of diffraction and there mention in far field, the diffraction pattern could be understood by Fourier transform. But I just don't understand what's the physical fact for that. And why cannot use Fourier transform for the the near-field case?

Also, when I am trying to understand the theory of [diffraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction), it ends up with some complicate math (integrals). I want to learn that but the books I am reading are not easy to understand. Anyone recommends some good books  or video lectures (more theoretical but to explain most of the math in plain way)?

Comment: I think that Fourier transform can be used for the far field (Fraunhofer diffraction) and the near case (Fresnel), but it's much more complicated. What math level do you have?

Comment: I wrote an answer about that [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/202/fourier-transformation-in-nature-natural-physics/230#230) a while ago...

Comment: @jinawee You are right, that the concept of Fourier transformation requieres a university math level. However the idea that this transformation allows easier understanding of periodic events. Such as in acoustics, where a note C shows a peak at $440\,$Hz in fourier/frequency spectrum.

Answer (score 2):

To give an unmathematical catchy answer, let's look at [Fraunhofer diffraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment) in [double slit experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Classical_wave-optics_formulation).
Interference at the observation plane depends on slit parameter $d$. What is the frequency of slits? E.g. $1\,\text{mm}\frac{1}{d}$: number of slits per length. Concluding frequiency in the setup. The following argumentation links this frequency to the fourier transform. The **physical significance is in the real optics setup**. The setup is easier described, when transformed in fourier space.

The double slit link on high school level above gives all the math without integrals. After **visualizing the following concept**, you see that the integrals are just math to convert the diffraction pattern in fourier space via [fourier transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Definition).

[image: Sketch with slit parameter d]

Using trigonometry first compute phase difference $\Delta\phi(\theta,d)$.
Go deeper in this concept using a sketch to visualize phase difference of $n\cdot\lambda$, $n\in\mathbf{N}$ as bright maxima in diffraction pattern. There is no magic in the next step. It's just a another point of view: Try to grasp $\frac{1}{d}$ as a parameter on its own: $\Delta\phi(\theta,\frac{1}{d})$.

Fourier space is a **synonym for [frequency domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_domain)**. Acoustics [examples are given](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/203/12234) in Eichenlaubs SE answer and [ptomatoes optics explanation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/230/12234).

No literature: Calculate and understand yourself with the links above.

Answer (score 0):

To make it short, my interpretation of the Fourier transform in optics is that is transforms **positions** (and phase) of the rays at some given plane, to their **angles**. One given angle corresponds to one given oscillation of the phase, i.e. one point on the Fourier space.